# Converting groupby pandas df of absolute numbers to percentage of row totals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in my df `df` that shows the 2 categories a user belongs to. For which I want to see the number of users for each category pair expressed as a %total of the row.

Original dataframe `df`:

```
+------+------+--------+
| cat1 | cat2 |  user  |
+------+------+--------+
| A    | X    | 687568 |
| A    | Y    |  68575 |
| B    | Y    |  56478 |
| A    | X    |   6587 |
| A    | Y    |  45678 |
| B    | X    |   5678 |
| B    | X    |    967 |
| A    | X    |    345 |
+------+------+--------+
```

I convert this to a groupby df using:
`df2 = df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2']).agg({'user': 'nunique'}).reset_index().pivot(index='cat1', columns='cat2',values='user')`to get the pairwise calculation of number of users per combination of categories (numbers here are made up):

```
+------+----+----+
| cat2 | X  | Y  |
+------+----+----+
| cat1 |    |    |
+------+----+----+
| A    |  5 |  5 |
| B    | 10 | 40 |
+------+----+----+
```

And I would like to convert the numbers to percent totals of the rows (Cat1), e.g. for the first row, 5/(5+5) = 0.5 and so on to give:

```
+------+-----+-----+
| cat2 |  X  |  Y  |
+------+-----+-----+
| cat1 |     |     |
| A    | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| B    | 0.2 | 0.8 |
+------+-----+-----+
```

Would I have to create a new column in my grouped df that contains the row-wise sum, and then iterate through each value in a row and divide it by that total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your expression:

```
piv = df.pivot_table('user', 'cat1', 'cat2', aggfunc='nunique')
pct = piv.div(piv.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> piv
cat2  X  Y
cat1      
A     3  2
B     2  1

>>> pct
cat2         X         Y
cat1                    
A     0.600000  0.400000
B     0.666667  0.333333
```